Books series about a girl and boy who could walk between worlds via books
I recall reading a young adult books series years ago. It was 3-book series.
I recall the plot being about a girl living with her grandma. She required special glasses to see, as she was blinded by the Sun. She one day came across a cavern entrance and explored it and discovered she had great vision underground. I vaguely recall something about gems being involved, but essentially she discovered she could walk between worlds via books. She discovered an abandoned city underground with glowing lichen and a lake and found a boy who was the same as her. There was also her father, who was still alive and started to hunt her down. The boy and girl used the books to escape her father. At the end of the series, the two explored more books, hoping that more of their society escaped a calamity into the books.
My son wants to read something interesting and I thought of this. Help me please?

In roughly which year/s did you read these books? And do you recall anything about any of the covers?

Between 2002 and 2007. It looked like a Celtic ornament with 3 gems. It was a condensed version. 3 separate books in one book. Was around a thousand pages

So, as @umopapisdn suggests, there's a lot in common with the Myst books, although your description isn't quite straight on.

the three books are Book of Atrus, Book of Ti'ana, and Book of D'ni. All 3 were collected in The Myst Reader, which does have a cover like you describe.  They do not have one long plot, Atrus being  prequel to Myst the video game, Ti'ana being a prequel to Atrus, and D'ni being a generation later sequel.
the power lies not with the kids, but in the books, which are made to be portals linking to other worlds instead of reading books
the 'father' is probably Gehn, Atrus' father from the Book of Atrus, and generally a villain obsessed with rebuilding the glory of D'ni in all the wrong ways. Their escape from Gehn locks him out of D'ni and sets up the opening to Myst (the player finds the book that Atrus lost)
the city underground with the lit lake is D'ni, a civilization that traveled there using their magic portal books and were quite comfortable, but fell apart during Ti'ana's story.
Atrus is Ti'ana's grandson, (not a girl) was living with her above ground when Gehn came back to take him to the ruin of D'ni
the girl you describe has elements of Catherine, a prodigy Gehn had found that bonded with Atrus, and Anna, a geologist who lives with her father that eventually discovered D'ni and took the name Ti'ana
Book of D'ni does feature Atrus and Catherine finding an ancient book in D'ni ruins and making contact with an offshoot civilization

There's a fair bit of pureblood/mudblood nonsense, to steal an easy term, that drives a lot of the conflict, and might explain some of the fuzzy bits.

Thank you. It's been years since I read the series. I had no idea it was built around a game and I am not quite elegant with my words anymore. However I do believe you have given me am answer I was looking for. Given that 5 of our 9 kids are gamers, I feel that this book set might hold their attention for more than a week. Thank you again.

@jocelynwarren If so, you can click the checkmark by the voting buttons to accept, as per the [tour].

Sounds like it could be the Myst series by Rand Miller - there is an omnibus of the 3 books, and the underground/books part would fit.

You might want to add details to help the askers memory
